# PHP Compression Options

Tags: php, file, binary, compression

I need to compress some binary files as quickly as possible with PHP - it needs to be reasonably fast and easy to use. What options can you fantastic people recommend? :)

Jamie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have any personal experience with them but there's a whole section in the docs on [Compression and Archive Extensions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.compression.php)

It looks like there are extensions for

- [Bzip2](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bzip2.php)
- [LZF](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.lzf.php)
- [Phar](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.phar.php)
- [Rar](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.rar.php)
- [Zip](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php)
- [Zlib](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.zlib.php)

If you're working directly with files on the server, the [ZipArchive](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php) class (that comes with the Zip extension) looks like it might be the easiest to use.

Comment: bz2 will usualy provide the best compression but if it is being given to users its best to use zip

Comment: How can I get bz2 on Windows, the docs don't seem to mention anything for windows.

Answer (score 0):

If clients are going to be downloading these you can setup Apache to compress them as they are served.

If it is something where you are going to be storing them on the server you can [PHPZip](https://www.php.net/zip) them.

Answer (score 0):

If the extension is available on your server or if you can add it, [LZF](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/book.lzf.php) is what you're looking for. Otherwise, [gzcompress()](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.gzcompress.php) with a compression level of 3 or less will be plenty fast.